# angularjs create new json array from existing array based on id as key remaining objects are values

Tags: angularjs, json

I have bookingData.roomList,

```
bookingData.roomList = [{id : <>, roomCategory : Single, number : 2}, {id:<>,roomCategory : Double, number : 1}]
```

And i want to make a new values like roomListData

```
roomListData = {<uuid> : {roomCateghory : Single, number : 2}, 
                <uuid1> : {roomCateghory : Double, number : 2} }
```

please some one help me to solve this

Comment: yeah i checked it's working fine. thanks for your support bro. thanks for everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. using JavaScript [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop :**

```js
var bookingData = {
 "roomList": [{
  id: 1,
  roomCategory: "Single",
  number: 2
 }, {
  id: 2,
  roomCategory: "Double",
  number: 1
 }]
};

var roomListData = {};

for(var i in bookingData.roomList) {
  roomListData[bookingData.roomList[i].id] = {
    "roomCategory" : bookingData.roomList[i].roomCategory,
    "number" : bookingData.roomList[i].number
  }
}

console.log(roomListData);
```

**2. using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) method with ES6 [Arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function :**

```js
var bookingData = {
 "roomList": [{
  id: 1,
  roomCategory: "Single",
  number: 2
 }, {
  id: 2,
  roomCategory: "Double",
  number: 1
 }]
};

var roomListData = {};

bookingData.roomList.map(item =>
  roomListData[item.id] = {
    "roomCategory" : item.roomCategory,
    "number" : item.number
  });

console.log(roomListData);
```

**3. using ES6 Spread assignment :**

```js
var bookingData = {
 "roomList": [{
  id: 1,
  roomCategory: "Single",
  number: 2
 }, {
  id: 2,
  roomCategory: "Double",
  number: 1
 }]
};

function createObj(a,b) {
  var roomListData = {};
  roomListData[a.id] = a,delete a.id;
  roomListData[b.id] = b,delete b.id;
  return roomListData;
}

var res = createObj(...bookingData.roomList);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think This is what you need. To use a property value as property label you use []

```
var roomList = [{id: 4514,roomCategory: "Single", number: 2}, 
                {id: 4542,roomCategory: "Double", number: 1}];

var newJson = [];
roomList.forEach(function(item) {
  newJson.push({
  [item.id] :{
        "roomCategory": item.roomCategory,
        "number": item.number
        }
  });
});
console.log(newJson);
```

Comment: How to iterate in the 'newJson' that has been created?

Answer (score 1):

`

```js
var roomList = [{id : 1, roomCategory : "Single", number : 2}, {id:2,roomCategory : "Double", number : 1}];
var roomListData = {};
for(var i=0;i< roomList.length ;++i){
    var temp =  roomList[i];
    var id = temp.id;
    delete temp.id;
    roomListData[id]=temp;
}
console.log(roomListData);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I assuming by uuid1 you mean a new uuid, not 'uuid' with the number 1 appended.

```
bookingData.roomList = [{id : <>, roomCategory : Single, number : 2}, {id:<>,roomCategory : Double, number : 1}]

roomList = {};
bookingData.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    var uuid = GenerateNewUUID();
    // or uuid = element.id;
    delete element.id;
    roomList[uuid] = element;
});
```